# Tracking Link Click on Google Tag Manager

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I want to track clicks on the following button/link with Google Tag Manager. I created a trigger in Google Tag Manager that triggers when the element_id = 100. This works fine, except that when I click exactly on the text, it doesn't do anything, the link looks like a button, with the text in the middle of it. I can't change anything to the html or css, otherwise I can think of multiple things, so I need to find a solution without changing the html. Also, the 'myclass' class and the 'label' class get used in other elements.

```
<a class="myclass" id="100" href="http://www.url.com">
<span class="label">Text</span>
</a>
```

Anyone an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: can you try changing `href="www.url.com"` to `href="http://www.url.com"`

Comment: Sorry, that's how actually it is, missed that when changing it to generic names.

Comment: What's the exact HTML you are using for your button? It would help to know for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following workaround worked:

- Create trigger when element text contains "Text". This will trigger events on the button and the label on the button, of all buttons with "Text" as label.
- Create tag for that trigger that checks with simple javascript if either the id of the current element = 100, which will happen when you click the button but not the label, or that the id of the parent = 100, which happens when you click the label. You can get the element that triggered the tag using the built-in variable "Click Element". Which you need to access the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you shouldn't have a CSS ID that starts with (or is) a number, so not sure if your code example is accurate or not. Whatever the case,  you're probably better off using "matches CSS selector" so that you don't need to use any custom JS.

[image]

If indeed your HTML uses `id="100"`, then the above will work. If it's anything else that doesn't start with a number, then you can use

```
#whatever > span
```

Comment: why not simply matches CSS selector `#100`?